Ad banner with Jetpack compose not loading ads
I am trying to add an ad banner to my Jetpack compose app. I am using AdMob but no ads are displayed:

I created an AdBanner() composable:
@Composable
private fun AdBanner() {
    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        factory = { context ->
            AdView(context).apply {
                setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER)
                adUnitId = context.getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id)
                loadAd(
                    AdRequest
                        .Builder()
                        .build()
                )
            }
        }
    )
}

I initialize ads in MainActivity.onCreate():
        val backgroundScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
        backgroundScope.launch {
            // Initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK on a background thread.
            Log.d(
                "MainActivity",
                "Initializing Google Mobile Ads SDK..."
            )
            MobileAds.initialize(this@MainActivity) {}
        }

I checked and double checked that my application id is set correctly in a <metadata> tag in AndroidManifest.xml and that my ad unit id is correct. What else can I check to troubleshoot this?
Edit (additional information):

I'm using a test ad unit with the Fixed Sized Banner id from here:
    <string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>


I added my phone as a test device to my Ad Mob account. I set up a shake gesture to view Ad Inspector which shows ads are not filled:



Logcat shows one error:

Invalid ID 0x00000000.

This doesn't seem very helpful since there is absolutely no additional information. There isn't even enough information to determine if this is an error with the ad banner or something else entirely.

I added an AdListener:
object : AdListener() {
                override fun onAdFailedToLoad(p0: LoadAdError) {
                    Log.d(
                        "AdBanner",
                        "Failed to load ad: ${p0.message}"
                    )
                }

                override fun onAdLoaded() {
                    Log.d(
                        "AdBanner",
                        "Ad loaded"
                    )
                }

                override fun onAdClicked() {
                    Log.d(
                        "AdBanner",
                        "Ad clicked"
                    )
                }

                override fun onAdClosed() {
                    Log.d(
                        "AdBanner",
                        "Ad closed"
                    )
                }

                override fun onAdImpression() {
                    Log.d(
                        "AdBanner",
                        "Ad impression"
                    )
                }

                override fun onAdOpened() {
                    Log.d(
                        "AdBanner",
                        "Ad opened"
                    )
                }

                override fun onAdSwipeGestureClicked() {
                    Log.d(
                        "AdBanner",
                        "Ad swipe gesture clicked"
                    )
                }
            }

This gives output like the following:

Ad loaded
Ad impression

This looks reasonable and what I would expect when ads load. There is no output from the onAdFailedToLoad().


On a side note, the Get Started Guide doesn't mention requesting internet permissions, but it seems like this is needed. I added it to AndroidManifest.xml, but still no luck:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Edit 2:
I'm using the AdBanner() composable like this:
    Scaffold(
        // ...
    ) { innerPadding ->
        Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            AdBanner()

            BaseballCardList(
                navController = navController,
                cards = stateList,
                onCardChanged = { index, card -> stateList[index] = card },
                contentPadding = innerPadding
            )

        // ...

    }


Are you initialising the MobileAds in the activity?
MobileAds.initialize(this) {}

@AshutoshWahane Thanks for the comment. Yes, I am iniitializing MobileAds inside CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch().

Have you tried confirmed that the AdBanner() composable itself is showing up? We can't tell from that screenshot what the expected outcome is, and we don't have the code that uses AdBanner(). So, might the problem be something like AdBanner() is winding up with zero height, or something like that?

@CommonsWare I used Layout Inspector to check that the AndroidView is indeed in the layout. It is the blank space between the AppTopBar and the first row in the list.

@CommonsWare Well, I thought the AdBanner() was that blank space. But now that I double check, the AdBanner() appears to be rendered at the top of the screen "under" the clock and notifications which I cut out of the screenshots I posted here.

@CommonsWare Thanks. This pointed me in the right direction. Turns out it is a layout issue, not an issue with using the AdMob SDK.

Turns out that it was a layout issue, not a problem with using the AdMob SDK. I ended up modifying the Column() that surrounds my AdBanner() with something like this:
    Scaffold(/* ... */) { innerPadding ->
        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
            AdBanner()
        }
    }


Few things I would suggest:

Test with test ad units id provided by Google https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads and see if you see any ads.
Try enabling test device https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#enable_test_devices
Check the logcat and see if there's any error
Add the callback to see if there's any error returned https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner#ad_events I am assuming you should see something in the fail callback which could help understand the issue futher.

override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError : LoadAdError) {
     // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
   }


Thanks for the suggestions. I edited my question with the results of each of these. Probably the most telling is my AdListener() which never logs the onAdFailedToLoad() method. In fact, the logs seem to all indicate success. But still no ad is rendered in the banner. Any other ideas about what to do from here?
